# Is calling someone 'master' of something shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, kufr

So basically what the title says, is it shirk to use the word 'master'? Like for example in sports games I see that sometimes people are called masters of that specific sport. And if it is shirk, is watching videos with the word 'master' in the title shirk too?

Comment: Also related: [Is saying “landlord” shirk?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69707/)

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't shirk to use the word master as one does not intend it in the way it is used for Allāh. There are many examples of the word master being used for humans in Qur'ān, Sunnah, statements of scholars etc.