# Is saying "landlord" shirk?

Tags: shirk

We usually say landlord for the owner of a house or a particular property. My question is whether calling the owner of the house landlord is shirk?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it isn't shirk because the meaning and usage are clear.

In Arabic you call a father or the person in charge:

> رب البيت     Rab al-Bayt
> (literally house lord or lord of the house).

And the qur'an and sunnah include lots of similar examples.

Answer (score 1):

It is not shirk when it is understood that *lord* means owner. Examples of this are present in the Quran and Hadith where the prophets use the term, and obviously they can not commit shirk.

From the Quran in the story of Prophet Joseph عليه السلام:

> فيسقي **ربه** خمرا
>
> he will give drink to his master of wine
>
> <sup>— [Quran 12:41](https://quran.com/12/41?translations=20)</sup>
>
> اذكرني عند **ربك** فأنساه الشيطان ذكر **ربه**
>
> "Mention me before your master." But Satan made him forget the mention [to] his master
>
> <sup>— [Quran 12:42](https://quran.com/12/42?translations=20)</sup>
>
> ارجع إلى **ربك**
>
> Return to your master
>
> <sup>— [Quran 12:50](https://quran.com/12/50?translations=20)</sup>

From the ahadith of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ:

> أن تلد الأمة **ربتها**
>
> When the slave woman gives birth to her mistress
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:8a)</sup>
>
> إذا ما **رب** النعم لم يعط حقها تسلط عليه يوم القيامة، فتخبط وجهه بأخفافها
>
> If the owner of camels does not pay their Zakat, then, on the Day of Resurrection those camels will come to him and will strike his face with their hooves.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6958)</sup>
>
> وحتى يكثر فيكم المال فيفيض حتى يهم **رب** المال من يقبل صدقته
>
> Till wealth will be in abundance so abundant that the owner of wealth will worry lest nobody should accept his Zakat
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7121)</sup>